# What version of theora is ffmpeg using

Tags: software-installation

I have compiled the recent version of ffmpeg with the support for theora encoding with libtheoa. Does anyone knows what version of theora is ffmpeg going to be using?

Is it 1.1.1 or 1.2.0 Alpha?

I have compiled ffmpeg and sadly I could not find the version that ffmpeg is using and I doubt that it is using the 1.2 version however I found a ffmpeg binary file that is using theora 1.2 alpha version ffmpeg2theora 0.29

Comment: Currently libav is being installed, not ffmpeg. Or are you using some older version of Ubuntu?

Comment: I know but I Want to encode a video to theora but I am interested what version of theora it is using the 1.1 version or 1.2

Comment: It is unfortunate, but i see that -version doesn't provide that info. If you need to be sure, you can compile it yourself, but be sure to use --prefix=/home/USERNAME/.local --bindir=/home/USERNAME/bin when you run configure script and then add /home/USERNAME/bin in the beginning of your PATH variable. This way you can later remove it and it won't conflict with stuff.

Comment: Thank you for your help yes I have compiled ffmpeg and sadly i could not find the version that ffmpeg is using and I doubt that it is using the 1.2 version however I found a ffmpeg binary file that is using theora 1.2 alpha version ffmpeg2theora 0.29

Comment: ffmpeg2theora is actually not really ffmpeg, it's a project based on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have compiled it yourself (as you've said in the comment) using `--enable-libtheora` during the configuration, then it will be the same thing as what is currently installed on your computer. You can check that by running

```
sudo apt-cache showpkg libtheora-dev
```

Comment: Mine shows 1.1.1, and since i'm at the latest Ubuntu running with all the updates, i would assume that yours wouldn't be any later than mine.

Comment: Yes it is 1.1.1+dfsg.1-3.1